# In Puerto Rico, how do you avoid "losing a game after having the most victory points?"

Tags: puerto-rico

I'm not talking about a situation where, on the last round of the game, you had the most victory points at the end of your turn, but someone playing after you passed you by, based on the victory points following his or her turn.

Suppose you have the most victory points, but aren't close to ending the game by using the captain or mayor. It look like one of your opponents is building, and more to the point, can fill the 12th city square with a building in one or two turns, whenever ready.

Is there any way to "head off" this person from winning by ending the game?

Put another way, should you try to keep piling up more victory points so that this opponent can't earn enough with the last building to have more than you? Or should to try to find a way to end the game as soon as possible so that no one catches up? And should the builder refrain from filling the city block if s/he has fewer victory points than you and can't earn enough to catch up on that turn?

Comment: It depends, and it isn't really clear what you are asking here. It looks like you are asking, if you have more VPs (all, buildings and chips) than any other player, is it possible for the change in VPs between you and an opponent over two governor phases to be greater than your current lead. (**this is obviously possible**, and isn't a good question.) Take for example the simplest case a 1VP lead, a Big Building is worth 4 points (assuming no one else wants to Mayor). That puts the +3 ahead of you, so if your building+shipping this round is worth X, and your opponent can ship X-2 they win.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The player with the most victory points at the end of the game will win. It is possible for a player with less victory points to overcome a player with more victory points.

Comment: @bengoesboom: I clarified the question by changing "whether?" to "how?"

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "enough victory points to win."  Nor does it matter who initiates the play that triggers the end of the game.  The only issue is, when the game ends, who has the most victory points.

There are three ways to trigger the end of the game.  If you are, in fact, in the lead, then your strategy should turn towards driving the game to its end quickly, in a way that prevents your opponents from scoring more points than you do.  Whether that involves "more building", "more mayoring", or "more shipping" depends on your situation.

Comment: So there is no, say, 10 point minimum as in "Settlers of Catan?" Maybe that is the source of my confusion.

Comment: Have you *played* Puerto Rico before?? It's not a race to X points; it's a race to *get the most points before the game ends*. And as **hymie** has mentioned, the game end can be triggered in three ways. Sometimes these all happend within the same round.